# Did Stalin personally tell Churchill that "the great bulk" of "10 millions" people were "wiped out" during collectivization?

Tags: united-kingdom, soviet-union

[The War Memoirs of Winston Churchill: Face to Face with Stalin](https://books.google.com/books?id=AkwEAAAAMBAJ&pg=PA104&dq=%22because%20you%20were%20not%20dealing%20with%20a%20few%20score%20thousands%20of%20aristocrats%20%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjO7Jmi-KrOAhVB6YMKHRW-DIIQ6AEIUzAJ#v=onepage&q=%22because%20you%20were%20not%20dealing%20with%20a%20few%20score%20thousands%20of%20aristocrats%20%22&f=false) Life Magazine 30 October 1950 at pages 104 and 106:

> [about 1am August 18, 1942]
>
> "I thought you would have found it bad," said I [Churchill], "because you were not dealing with a few score thousands of aristocrats or big landowners, but with millions of small men."
>
> "Ten millions," he [Stalin] said, holding up his hands. "It was fearful. Four years it lasted. It was absolutely necessary for Russia, if we were to avoid periodic famines..."...
>
> "What happened to them?" I [Churchill] asked.
>
> he [Stalin] said "...the great bulk were very unpopular and were wiped out by their laborers"

Is there any independent evidence that this conversation is or isn't accurately quoted?